# Laravel relationship between auto model instance

Tags: laravel

i'm work on project that require to make all step auto i mean user can add category with items "Regardless of the nature of the names of these category and items" .

and from back i will create new table for each " category and item " with name  like user send  and link tables with only two model One for Parent and anther for child item .

Now problem with get relationship **between instance of Parent & Child Model**

My Code

`$parent = new ParentModel('product_categories');`

`$related = new RelatedModel('products');`

My ParentModel Like :

`

```
public function childrens()
{
    return $this->hasMany(RelatedModel::class , 'parent_id' ,'id');
}
```

`

My RelatedModel Like :

`

```
public function __construct($table = null ,array $attributes = [])
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);
    $this->setTable($table);

}

public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(ParentModel::class , 'parent_id' ,'id');
}
```

`

Now when i pass different table name in instance  model its work fine and return all table data

`$query = $parent->newQuery()->get()`

But problem when i try get data with  these relationship dynamically

`$query = $parent->newQuery()->with('childrens')->get()`

laravel always ignore setTable() function and make query from
table name "related_models" not table i'm inject

this is problem show

`SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'related_models' doesn't exist`

and query like that

`select * from 'related_models' where 'related_models'.'parent_id' in (1,2)`

can i from these model pass only table name and get all data with relation

or can any one help to  make this logic sense

Thanks

Comment: Why would you make a table everytime a user registers a category?

Comment: i know i can solve by EAV model but client need all to create what he need in separate table and that will give us power of create all web dynamically

Comment: i think its wrong approach for this situation . and you have getting this error because of the table does not exist in database. try to migrate teh database if you where not using laravel migration feature may be a typo error on table name check it out

Answer (score 0):

The point of an ORM and models is to create a logical entrypoint to get data from te database. Going forth with an implementation like your's sounds like its not easy to follow for any new developer who looks at it, and it will eventually run into limitations.

What you could do if writing all the models is just to much work is creating abstracts:

```php
// parent abstract
abstract class Parent extends Model {
  abstract protected function childModel();

  public function childrens()
  {
    return $this->hasMany($this->childModel() , 'parent_id' ,'id');
  }
}

// parent implementation
class Product extends Parent {
  public function childModel()
  {
    return ProductCategories::class;
  }
}

// child abstract
abstract class Child extends Model {
  abstract protected function parentModel();

  public function parent()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo($this->parentModel() , 'parent_id' ,'id');
  }
}

// child implementation
class ProductCategories extends Child {
  public function parentModel()
  {
    return Product::class;
  }
}
```